# How to find and replace the prefix of a classname with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, regex, classname

I have a bunch of class names like `md:block` and `sm:flex`

I need to:

1. Find all classes that begin with '**md**' or '**sm**'.
2. Append '**-panel**' after each '**md**' and '**sm**'.
3. End up with `md-panel:block` and `sm-panel:flex`.

First attempt in comments: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61035473/4019931

Second attempt:

```js
/*
Add / remove prefixes to DOM element classes. Requieres JQuery.
https://gist.github.com/carloscabo/e0374676c614dd6e6ea19ad4b9ecf9a4
by Carlos Cabo 2016. MIT License.
How it works:
  1. Loops over the group of elements
  2. For each element if it has any class that matches the regex:
    a. If the prefix is NOT present -> adds
    b. If the prefix IS present -> removes
$jquery_selector, conatining group of elements where replacement will be done
regex, refired to the classname, all classes matching this selector in the group of elements will be un/prefixed
prefix, string that will be added / removed from matching classes
add, true = add prefix ( default value)
     flase = remove prefix
Adding 'pre-' to all classnames matched in regex:
addRemoveClassPrefix(
  $('#imgs-slider, #imgs-slider [class^=swiper]'), // JQuery selector: Group of elements where to be executed
  /^swiper/,                                      // RegEx: All classNames starting with 'swiper'
  'pre-'                                          // Add this prefix
);
Removing 'pre-' to all classnames matched in regex:
addRemoveClassPrefix(
  $('[class^=pre-swiper]'), // JQuery selector: Group of elements where to be executed
  /^pre-swiper/,           // RegEx: All classNames starting with 'swiper'
  'pre-'                   // Add this prefix
);
*/

function addRemoveClassPrefix( $jquery_selector, regex, prefix ) {
  if ($jquery_selector.length) {
    $jquery_selector.each( function(idx, el) {
      var
        $el = $(el),
        classes = $el.attr('class').split(' '),
        new_class;
      for (var i = 0; i < classes.length; i++) {
        if (regex.test( classes[i] )) {
          new_class = ( classes[i].indexOf( prefix ) === 0 ) ? classes[i].replace( prefix, '') : prefix+classes[i] ;
          $el.addClass( new_class ).removeClass( classes[i] );
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

I found this (https://gist.github.com/carloscabo/e0374676c614dd6e6ea19ad4b9ecf9a4) which almost does what I want. But I have 3 issues I can't figure out.

1. How to set the regex to /*md/ without it turning into a comment in the code.
2. How to set multiple things in the regex. /*sm/*md/ ?
3. How to change it so that it splits in the middle of the class name and adds the first part + prefix + last part. I tried this:

   `new_class = ( classes[i].indexOf( prefix ) === 0 ) ? classes[i].split('-panel:').join(':') : classes[i].split(':').join('-panel:');`

I need it to turn all 'md:value' to 'md-panel:value' and vice versa. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hmm, nothing obviously wrong with your code that I can see. Have you tried inspecting the jquery object/length, or reduced it to a simple example with static html?

Comment: Made a small [codepen](https://codepen.io/ifthenelse/pen/LYVKZZm), and you code looks ok. Maybe the `md:` elements are generated via js and they're not already added to the DOM when you run it?

Comment: Thanks @ne1410s + ifthenelse. I realised it was looking for a class value that began with "sm:" or "md:". But I didn't realise this meant of the whole set of classes. So when I had another class value before the "md:block" class, it didnt pick it up.

Fixed it by changing [class^=”value”] to [class*=”value”] and it worked!

Answer (score 2):

Figured one solution :)

```js
$('[class*="sm:"], [class*="md:"]').attr("class", function(i, val) {
  return val.split(":").join("-panel:");
});
```

Comment: +1 for working that out. One side-effect to bear in mind with this code however is that **any** colons (`:`) in your class name will now be prefixed with `-panel`, if and only if they happen to also contain `md:` or `sm:`.

Comment: Yea that’s the idea. sm and md classes set the responsive breakpoints based on screen width. So when the side panel is open, the content area doesn’t adapt in the right place. So I needed to change the break points when it’s open and replace all sm and md classes to sm-panel and md-panel.

Comment: Yes, it's just that if you had an innocent class called "hello:test" or anything with a `:` then this would sometimes also be changed to `hello-panel:test`, and other times preserved.  Whether it changed or not would be in accordance to whether it also had an md: or sm:.  It's may not ever manifest as a problem, but is a bug waiting to be unearthed!

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. Need to be more explicit. I’ll keep this in mind! Not sure how else to do it. Thanks 

Comment: OK, it caused a bug already. ha. So I don't know how I was get the return value to be the correct selector. I tried `return val.split(val).join("-panel");`

Answer (score -1):

Use hasclass and replace

```
$('this').hasClass('md').replace('md-panel')
```